# Compile with Haskell Stack in environment with limited memory

Tags: haskell-stack

By default, the Haskell Stack tool seems to build projects in parallel with as many cores are available. In environments with limited memory (low memory per core), this can lead to out of memory or thrashing swap.

Is there a way to run `stack install <package>` while reducing the number of threads? (I see no such option in the help message.)

Comment: Try `-j1`. See `stack --help`.

Comment: Aha. It's listed under `stack --help` but not `stack install --help`. I guess I should have thought of that. Thanks!